# Android studio error could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1

Tags: android

I install android studio and create a project, but I have this errors:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
```

Open File
Show Details

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
```

Open File
Show Details

and this is source:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
 compileSdkVersion 26
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hosein.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }    }}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

}

Comment: make sure you have not enabled offline work in settings android studio. and it not then make sure internet is working.

Comment: What is the build tool version?